# Is there a way to set some values in the multiple dimensional json array

Tags: karate

```
Scenario Outline: Explore Karate '<ID>'
* karate.set($attributesFirstRun[*].created_timestamp,'#present')
* karate.set($attributesSecondRun[*].created_timestamp,'#present') 

* match attributesFirstRun == attributesSecondRun
Examples:
   | read('Sample.csv') |
```

I tried this. But I'm getting this error

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:42 Expected an operand but found *
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-thinking this. Karate is actually just plain JS. And sounds like you are trying to do a "bulk update" via JsonPath - sorry, that's not supported, perhaps you would be interested in contributing code.

Here's the solution for updating all elements of an array:

```
* def before = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }]
* def after = before.map(x => ({ a: x.a * 5 }))
* match after == [{ a: 5 }, { a: 10 }]
```

Keep in mind updating JSON is easy:

```
* def data = {}
* data.a = 1
* match data == { a: 1 }
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms